# Laravel multiple counts with conditions from one table

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `orders` table and need to combine multiple counts depending on specific conditions.

At the moment I have 3 queries :

```
$orderCount = Order::count();
$newOrderCount = Order::where('status', '=', 'new')->count();
$completedOrderCount = Order::where('status', '=', 'completed')->count();
```

How can this be combined into 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with eloquent but the first solution that came to my mind

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as order_count'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('sum(case when status = "new" then 1 else 0 end) as new_orders_count'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('sum(case when status = "completed" then 1 else 0 end) as completed_orders_count'))
    ->get();
```

---

Or do it with the collection:

```
$orders = Order::all();
$orderCount = $orders->count();
$newOrderCount = $orders->where('status', '=', 'new')->count();
$completedOrderCount = $orders->where('status', '=', 'completed')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

A long-winded solution, but would do the trick as well.

```php
$orders = Order::all(['id'])->toArray();
$orderCount = 0;
$newOrderCount = 0;
$completedOrderCount = 0;

array_map(function ($o) use (&$orderCount, &$newOrderCount, &$completedOrderCount) {
    $orderCount++;

    if($o['status'] === 'new')
        $newOrderCount++;

    if($o['status'] === 'completed')
        $completedOrderCount++;

}, $orders);
```

Comment: `$orders.each` looks a little non-standard. Is that intended or a typo?

Comment: @shaedrich, Oops, my bad. Mistook `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` with `Illuminate\Support\Collection `. Fixed!. Thanks for the correction.